# Problem in Integrating Quartz with Spring Batch

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-batch

I am trying to use spring batch & quartz in a project. The objective is to schedule a spring-batch job using Quartz. I have the following beans -

```
bean id="updateDataFeedJob"  class="package.UpdateDataFeedJob" />     

<bean id="UpdaterOnScheduleJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="updateDataFeedJob"/>
    <!-- the method to call inside of com.siemens.scr.schedule.UpdateDataFeedJob -->
    <property name="targetMethod" value="execute"/>
</bean> 

<bean id="cronTriggerId" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="UpdaterOnScheduleJobDetail" />
    <!-- run every morning at 3AM -->
    <!--  <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 3 * * ?" /> -->

    <!-- Fires every five minutes -->
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/5 * * * ?" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTriggerId" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The UpdateDataFeedJob is -

```
public class UpdateDataFeedJob  {   
  public void execute() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Hello World. Running the job");
    CommandLineJobRunner.main(new String[]{"GetFleetUpdatesJob.xml", "getFleetUpdatesJob"});
  }  
}
```

Sample Calling is -

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //CommandLineJobRunner.main(new String[]{"GetFleetUpdatesJob.xml", "getFleetUpdatesJob"});
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("GetFleetUpdatesJob.xml");
    }   
}
```

I keep getting the following exception -

```
ERROR - Job Terminated in error: A job execution for this job is already running: JobInstance: id=0, JobParameters=[{}], Job=[getFleetUpdatesJob]
org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException: A job execution for this job is already running: JobInstance: id=0, JobParameters=[{}], Job=[getFleetUpdatesJob]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:112)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:98)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:448)
    at com.siemens.scr.schedule.UpdateDataFeedJob.execute(UpdateDataFeedJob.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:276)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:260)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working. I am not aware of the exact reason & will appreciate if someone can comment -

I added the following bean config in the **applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager"/>
```

Now i dont get that exception & quartz is able to call the spring batch job

Comment: As you found, Spring Batch wants a transactionManager - even if it is the stub `ResourcelessTransactionManager`. Also, you could set the Quartz job as `Stateful`. Quartz will not launch another instance of the job until the previous instance has been completed.

Answer (score 1):

Spring batch differentiates between different executions of same job with the help of Job parameters supplied.

As seen in your code sample, you are passing no Job parameters hence all job executions will be same according to spring batch and any instance which is stuck in running state will cause spring batch to throw JobAlreadyRunningException.

Comment: yes this is why you see job already running exception. If you add job parameters like sys date time, it should work

Answer (score 0):

We had same issue.  We were worried someone might tighten the quartz window and quartz does not have the `ScheduleExector.scheduleAtFixedDelay`.  It only has the `shceduleAtFixedRate` so batch jobs "could" overlap so we:

1. add job parameters to make the job unique
2. put a static variable in our Java quartz trigger that has an `isRunning`field so we don't let the job run two instances in one JVM in case they put the period to be too tight.